# Locating balls on pool table using OpenCVSharp

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

I'm trying to detect circles on an image, however I don't know what I'm doing wrong but the code is getting for me only 2 circles on the right as shown on the image below:

[image: Circle]

Here it is the code that I have tried:

```
using System;

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;
using OpenCvSharp;
using Point = System.Drawing.Point;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Mat image = Cv2.ImRead(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\pool.jpg", ImreadModes.Color);

            Mat cImage = image.Clone();

            Mat grayedColor = new Mat();
            
            Cv2.CvtColor(cImage, grayedColor, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
            
            var cirlce = Cv2.HoughCircles(grayedColor, HoughModes.Gradient, 1.2, 1);

            
            foreach (var cirl in cirlce)
            {
                cImage.Circle(cirl.Center.ToPoint(), (int)cirl.Radius, Scalar.Magenta, 2, LineTypes.Link4);
            }
            
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
            timer.Start();
            
            Cv2.ImShow("Original", cImage);
            Cv2.ImShow("Grayed Color", grayedColor);
            
            Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed.ToString(@"m\:ss\.fff"));
            
            Cv2.WaitKey();
            Cv2.DestroyAllWindows();
            
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Please if you post a solution explain to me what I'm doing wrong exactly.

Comment: forget hough, forget canny. you need to work with chroma masking, to select the dark green background. (medianBlur, cvtColor, inRange) like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yh3TV.png or just throw AI at it. it's good at locating objects.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thank you, I'm gonna try to search and try to make a result like in your image